# iOS - View order when creating a constraint

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslayoutconstraint

When creating a constraint (programmatically or from interface builder) does it matter the order of the views? Does it matter which is the first item and which is the second item ?

Comment: didn't get from you clearly.Are you asking order for adding constraints to view or placing view in hierarchy?

Comment: Let's say we add a leading constraint on view A and view B by using Interface Builder. After we select it and in the Size Inspector we have the following drop-down menus: First Item (which is view A.Leading), Relation (equal for example), Second Item (which is view B.Leading). Here we have the option to reverse the first item with the second item. Does it matter which is the first item and which is the second item?

Comment: Also let's say we have view A as the root view and view B as a child of view A with top, bottom, leading, trailing constraints. Each constraint is defined as view A.ConstraintX Equal view B.ConstraintX (Constant 0). By doing this view B will be stretched in A (root view).
Now if we reverse A and B does it mean that the root view will be forced to resize to view B?

Comment: No, the root view will always be the full size of its container.  Autolayout will attempt to resolve the layout by determining fixed items and the priorities of constraints.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it does, because the `constant` value is added to the second item to determine the value of the first item.

So, if you have `label2.leading = label1.trailing + 45` then you get something like:

[image]

But if you have `label1.trailing = label2.leading + 45` you get:

[image]

because the trailing edge of `label1` now needs to be 45 away from the leading edge of `label2`, which means that `label2` is on top of `label1`

If I say `label1.trailing = label2.leading + -45` then I will have the same as in the first instance:
[image]

You would have similar issues with top/bottom constraint items too.

If you select *Reverse first and second items* in Interface Builder, then it will switch the sign of the constant for you.  If you are doing it programatically then you need to account for this yourself.

Comment: Constraints are *bidirectional* though, right? (if constraints were "directional" – like eg variable assignment, `label2.leading = label1.trailing` would only affect `label2.leading`)

Comment: I don't know what you mean by bidrectional. Constraints between two objects establish a relationship between those two objects. Autolayout can move one or the other or both of those objects in an attempt to satisfy the constraint. You need enough constraints to prevent ambiguity or you get a warning at runtime. E.g. if I just constrained label 1 & 2 to each other, it would be ambiguous. You can see in my screenshot a cutoff constraint in the leading edge of label 1.  If this constraint is to the fixed edge of the view the ambiguity is resolved. Label 2 moves.

Comment: That's right – by "bidirectional" I mean: "Autolayout can move one or the other or both of those objects in an attempt to satisfy the constraint." Note OP's commented example using `constant: 0` – there are two possible questions here: 1. (my "bidirectional" question) Does an Autolayout constraint affect the layout of both items, or only the first item? – answer: yes; and 2. (the question you answer here) If an Autolayout constraint uses a non-identity constant/multiplier, does the order of the items matter? – answer: yes.